# Lazy evaluation of yield'ed values

Tags: python-3.x, lazy-evaluation

To the best of my knowledge, generators are lazy but nor very lazy. Whenever you use a generator, the yielded expression is evaluated upon passing it using next, eventhough it is only evaluated at this moment.

In the particular use case of finding the 'length' of a generator `sum(1 for _ in generator)` or when only certain elements are used `[x for idx, x in enumerate(generator) if i%2==1]`, this is a shame.

I was wondering whether there is a transparant way to return or yield objects as expressions which are automatically evaluated when being used (not called): as is done in Haskell.

Consider this example as an expensive function:

```
## Some expensive 'constructor'/'creator' for objects

def create_object(x):
    print('expensive computation')
    return 2*x
```

Naively this would be the general approch when using it in a generator:

```
## Naive approach:
print("NAIVE")
def special_objects(n, parity):
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == parity:
            yield create_object(i)
```

Eventhough the generator is expensive, it is also intuitive and easy to use:

```
# Is expensive, as every yielded expression is evaluated:           
print( sum(1 for _ in special_objects(5, 1)) )

# but also is 'transparent', you don't have to explicitely evaluate each element
# (except looping through the elements, but this is the generator's lazy
# evaluation, not that of the object's evaluation itself.
print(list(special_objects(5, 1)))
```

An alternative, however, is less intuitive but also less expensive:

```
## A factory approach
print("FACTORY")

def special_object_factories(n, parity):
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == parity:
            yield lambda: create_object(i)

# Is efficient, as none of the objects are created at all:
print( sum(1 for _ in special_object_factories(5, 1)) )

# But it is not transparent, you have to evaluate the objects yourself and cache
# the values if you need them multiple times.
print([o() for o in special_object_factories(5, 1)])
```

Is there a transparent way to return or yield expressions which are evaluated lazy (i.e. not using lambda's which you need to cache and evaluate manually, and not something that has caveats)?

In C++14 you can write all kinds of fancy wrapper-classes to do this, which only really 'become' something if they are 'dereferenced' or 'used' in some way, I was wondering if there is something like this for Python 3.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense in Python - you could return an object with a lazily-evaluated attribute (using `@property`), but not make the object itself lazily evaluated without either calling it (`()`) or indexing into it (`[]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found (in google) lot of articles about lazy evaluation in Python and generally most of them say that using lambdas and generators, as you did, is "good enough" but not perfect method. I also found at least two modules that tries to implement lazy evaluation: [lazypy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazypy/) and [lazy_python](https://github.com/llllllllll/lazy_python).

I think the second one might be good one, as it allows to use `@lazy_function` decorator to force interpreter to create so called `thunks` and evaluate it when you really need it. However I did not test this module and I noticed it has several known bugs and limitations.